# Can I use regex in SharePoint GetListItems web service

Tags: regex, web-services, sharepoint

I need to list all the files located in one document library that match a specific naming convention: The documents to retrieve are all in the form 'Report xxxx-xx-xx'.

I have to use the GetListItems web service.

Is there a way to collect all these documents in one call?
How to write the 'where' section in the query part?
Can I use some regex in this?

Thanks

Comment: You could also try posting this question on [SharePoint.stackexchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Reading

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093(v=office.12).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414805(v=office.12).aspx

the construction of a `WHERE` clause seems clear:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Expires"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">
        <Today/>
      </Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

However there does not seem to be a way to use regexes. Perhaps the best you can do is to use the `BeginsWith` element on the "Report" and `Contains` element to search for a dash. There is a good example for this at

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196501(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I am already using the "BeginsWith" option but it's not what I want because it returns too many documents that did not match my pattern

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could add a [Calculated Column](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/calculate-data-in-lists-or-libraries-HA010105480.aspx) on your document library, that performs a string manipulation and/or test operation on your title text, and returns eg something that can then easily be picked up in your where clause?

This might help limit the result set at the server side...

`=IF(LEFT([TitleColumn],7)="Report ", if(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(RIGHT([TitleColumn],10))), "TRUE", "FALSE"), "FALSE")`

Refer to [Microsoft's Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) for what's available in calculated columns.